# Is the spell Haste (1 x per short rest) as a Warlock invocation too powerful without a level prerequisite?

Tags: dnd-5e

Is the spell Haste as a Warlock invocation too powerful without a level prerequisite?

I'm putting together a Flash based Warlock with the patron "The Speed Force". I'm currently thinking of making new Invocations and or rewording some existing Invocations, Spells or similar effects; ones like Armor of Shadows as Lightning Reflexes. Haste has to be one of them. Is Haste every short rest too powerful an invocation as it is to have at Lv2 cause it gives more perks than Action Surge?

Would it be better to have it as an Invocation with a prerequisite of being 5th level?

I could also just turn Action Surge per short rest as an Invocation that can be selected at 2nd Lv and have improve at 5th Lv by replacing it with Haste?

Comment: I suggest you separate the question about action surge and haste as invocations. We have a 1 question per post policy, here. Putting those two together will deter potential answerers from posting one answer for one question if they dont know the answer to the other

Comment: Also, are you considering Haste as an upgrade to Action Surge?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to start a discussion. That's the kind of post that doesn't work here. For that you might want to try [a discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) instead, where you can get feedback, throw around ideas, and discuss your homebrew thoughts without having to shoehorn it into our Question/Answer site format.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to introduce Haste before 5th level when 3rd level spells become available? From a design perspective that can be unbalancing on it's own.